# why cant ubuntu 14.04 install on my windows 8.1

Tags: software-installation

please can you tell me how to install ubuntu on my windows 8.1 ive tried to install with the disk. But its not installing its saying missing file from the disk but it installed on another laptop.

Answer (score 0):

What model of computer do you have? What OS was the second computer? windows 8.1 uses UEFI to start up, which is different from an older OS, which would use BIOS.

Comment: the model of the computer is HP Pavillion G6

Answer (score 0):

if you having license version of windows 8.1 than you might be not installing Ubuntu.

you might be install Ubuntu using **wubi**.

[Help for Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: i've tried it its not working.